# How can I add a comma & space after every two digits in Excel and then format the text?

Tags: excel

Here's the table I'm working with:

[image]

First off, how can I separate the string of numbers in column C so that they have a comma and space after every two digits?

I was able to partially finish it, but for some reason I can't grab the last two digits. I used this formula:

```
=MID(C4,1,2)&", "&MID(C4,3,2)&", "&MID(C4,6,2)&", "&MID(C4,10,2)&", "&MID(C4,13,2)&", "&MID(C4,16,2)
```

After that I need to somehow format that string to look like the example in column E, that's where I'm really confused. Maybe I don't even need the first step?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you already have access to `TEXTJOIN` formula then it will quickly become your best friend :-)

I assume that your values are in column C (starting from cell C1) and that the column is formatted as text.

Try:

```
="""stats"":["&TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,MID(C1,ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(C1)/2))*2-1,2))&"]"
```

If your Office 365 version is not using dynamic arrays yet, try entering the formula with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`:

[image]

Comment: nice, use of INDEX instead of volatile INDIRECT.

Comment: Thanks Scott! It's actually one of many useful things that I learned on this forum :-)

Comment: @JustynaMK Thanks for the response. I tried you formula but it looks like im only pulling the first two digits. https://imgur.com/a/jI5UK7K

I double checked and column C is formatted as text. Where do you think im going wrong?

Comment: @EB_Crypto Ah might be the difference in Excel versions. I was checking the formula on Office 365 but the one that is already taking care of Dynamic Arrays (pretty cool feature!). Try entering this formula but using `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` (to turn it into an array). I also forgot to lock some cells so please check my updated answer.

Comment: @JustynaMK thank you very much - worked perfectly! I'm new to TEXTJOIN, if you don't mind could you please explain the significance of the "/2))*2-1,2)" portion at the end. How would that change if say I only needed a comma after 1 digit instead of 2? Thanks!

Comment: @EB_Crypto Glad it worked for you! This part  `MID(C1,ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(C1)/2))*2-1,2))` can be broken down as follows: take text in cell `C1` (left part of the formula) and take `2` characters (right part of the formula) from the middle position, specified as -> `ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(C1)/2))*2-1` (middle part of the formula). The middle part is an "artificial" array of numbers which I'll explain in the second post that follows :-)

Comment: As our text in cell `C1` has 12 characters -> `LEN(C1)`, we only need to take 1st, 3rd, 5th, 7th, 9th and 11th positions into account. So your MID formula will look like: `MID(C1, 1, 2)`, `MID(C1,3,2)`, `MID(C1,5,2)` and so on... Now in order to achieve that, you need to return a row number from a range, like ROW(A1:A6)` `(A6 = LEN(C1)/2)`. This will give you numbers {1,2,3,4,5,6}. As our ultimate goal is to actually return {1,3,5,7,9,11}, you need to multiply {1,2,3,4,5,6} by 2 and subtract 1.

Comment: Does it make sense? Sorry if it's a little bit messy! But just to answer your initial question, to retrieve all values with a comma after 1 digit, you'd need to use: `="""stats"":["&TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,MID(C1,ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(C1))),1))&"]"`.

Comment: @JustynaMK I understood all that very clearly. Thank you for taking the time to help & explain. You saved me a TON of time. Much appreciated

Comment: You're most welcome :-) I suggest getting familiar with `TEXTJOIN` (already available) and also `Dynamic Arrays` (launching soon) functionalities, both real time savers! Take care.